# Reformatting comments with gq, using spaces in 'comments'

Tags: formatting, comments, wrapping, textwidth

I'm using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to automatically reformat JavaScript (well, TypeScript, but same deal in this situation) source-code.

It enforces a comment-style like this, with leading spaces replaced with `·`:

```javascript
···/**
····*·Foo bar baz,
····*·something something!
····*/
```

Note that in a three-space width, the `*` is *centered*. This is contrary to what Vim likes to do with the default `'comments`' setting of `s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/`. For example, when typing exactly the keys `<Space><Space><Space>/* test<CR>test2<CR>|`, you end up with the following:

```javascript
   /*
   * test
   * test2
   * |
```

This wouldn't be a huge problem, as I can depend on Prettier to undo that hot mess when it reformats the source-code. However, what *is* a huge problem, is that this screws up the `'textwidth'`: a line that *is* within `'tw'` when the asterisk is misaligned can become *outside* the `'tw'` once reformatted to align the asterisks.

To fix this, I've attempted adding the whitespace to the `'comments'` setting, as described in `:help option-backslash` and `:help 'comments'`:

```
:set comments=s1:/*,mb:\ *\ ,ex:\ */,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
```

Unfortunately, not only does this not work as expected, but it completely breaks the `fo+=j` line-joining behaviour — the  `*`  gets retained when joining comment-lines.

How can I use Vim to write comments *within* a fixed text-width, while also using Prettier?

Answer (score 1):

What version of vim are you using?

With `vim -Nu NONE` and `:filetype plugin indent on`, `:syn on` I don't have that issue:

[image]

Default `set comments` I have for javascript is

```
  comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

Comment: I did have this issue with `vim --clean` and `setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/`, at least I think I did, lol